# Ajax подгрузка картинка в битриксе?

Tags: битрикс

каким образом можно сделать ajax подгрузку изображений в слайдере.
На одной странице имеются 3 слайдера, каждый слайдер имеет по 30 изображений( первый и вовсе имеет 80 картинок)
Даже если уменьшить изображения и оптимизировать их , все равно получается огромный вес. Каким образом можно сделать ajax подгрузку . К примеру загружать по 10 слайдов

Comment: А картинки с бека приходят?

Comment: да конечно, все из бэка

Comment: Не знаком с битриксом, но думаю там много плагинов для пагинации. Просто подключите плагин и подставляйте необходимые переменные (limit, page)  в запрос по которому получаете картинки